# How can I prints the sum of the 2nd to last digit of each integer?

Tags: java, sum

How can I print the sum of the 2nd to last digit of each integer?

(so, 8 would be printed since 1 + 3 + 4 is 8) in the following Program:

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Pr6{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int sumSecToLast;

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num1 = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num2 = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num3 = scan.nextInt();

      sumSecToLast = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10;
          System.out.print((num1/10) % 10 + " + " + (num2/10) % 10 + " + " + (num3/10) % 10 + " = " + sumSecToLast);


      }//main
}//Pr6
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num1 % 10` is the last digit

`(num1/10) % 10` is the second to last digit.

Therefore, if you want to calculate the sum of the next to last digits of the 3 input integers, change your code to :

```
sumLastD = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10;
```

Comment: shaloom adoni , but the op said this 1 + 3 + 4 is 8 why?

Comment: @KickButtowski OP didn't say what input they entered. If they entered 16 37 42, the next to last digits would be 1,3 & 4 and the sum would be 8.

Comment: toda raba make more sense

Comment: Your explanation explains what OP wants, now your answer make sense, +1.

Comment: @Eran when I edited the program to this;  sumSecToLast = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10; As a result it printed:
1 + 3 + 4 = 0 , while 16 + 37 + 42 = 8. WHY?? Whats wrong?

Comment: @Bader 1,3 and 4 have no second to last digit (since they only have one digit), so the second to last digit is 0. 0+0+0 = 0. In 16,37 & 42, the second to last digits are 1,3 & 4 and the sum is 8. Nothing is wrong.

Comment: @Eran so how can i modify it so that if i inserted one digit it declare it as the second to the last?

Comment: @Bader `num1>=10?((num1/10) % 10):num1 + num2>=10?((num2/10) % 10):num2 + num3>=10?((num3/10) % 10):num3`

Comment: @Eran can you edit the entire program from the main question with the modification you advised. because I tried to make the changes you gave, but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

@Bader, Try this Code.. Will work...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int sumLastD;

                  System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
       num1 = scan.nextInt();

                  System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
       num2 = scan.nextInt();

                  System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
       num3 = scan.nextInt();

     System.out.println(num1+" -- "+num2+" -- "+num3);

       int divideBy1 = 0;
       int divideBy2 = 0;
       int divideBy3 = 0;



       if(num1>10 && num1<100)
           divideBy1=10;
       else if(num1>100 && num1<1000)
           divideBy1=100; 

      if(num2 >10 && num2<100)
           divideBy2=10;
      else  if(num2>100 && num2<1000)
           divideBy2=100;

      if(num3>10 && num3<100)
           divideBy3=10;
      else  if(num3>100 && num3<1000)
           divideBy3=100;


       int ans1=0,ans2=0,ans3=0;

       if(num1<10)
           ans1=num1;
       else
           ans1=num1 % divideBy1;


       if(num2<10)
           ans2=num2;
       else
           ans2=num2% divideBy2;


       if(num3<10)
           ans3=num3;
       else
           ans3=num3 % divideBy3;



       sumLastD = ans1+ans2+ans3;
       System.out.println("Total = " + sumLastD);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you mean the sum of all 3 integers your formula should be like this.

```
sumLastD = num1 + num2 + num3;
```

If that was not what your meant, sorry but your question is a little vague.

Comment: This is now what OP meant, he wants to extract *one to last* digit from an `int`, meaning if the integer is 132, 3 will be returned.

Comment: @MarounMaroun agreed..